# PHP Dealing with cookies when scraping webpage with CURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape pages but I fail with many pages because of cookies. I think I need to take the page's cookies and put them into `CURLOPT_COOKIE`. But I still don't get the content of such type of page.

URL to CURL: http://www.roguefitness.com/reebok-crossfit-speed-teal-dust-forest-grey-black-hery-yellow-skull-grey

```
$cookie = array();
$cookie[] = "visid_incap_626072=wppfexB2Rx2G+0Fl0p5ObF3HRlkAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABkbU4BWHOCgsesm58ql+4y";
$cookie[] = "incap_ses_415_626072=L8pAJA2442e3l2pfKmHCBV3HRlkAAAAAK0T9IPzsPD+zRr2W8AY4kA==";
$cookie[] = "incap_ses_541_626072=BGgpDAFx32HueJcV/QSCB5nHRlkAAAAAysy38ULGSs0RqTsyx2QsJg==";
$cookie = implode('; ', $cookie);

$cookieJar = tempnam ("/dev/null", "CURLCOOKIE");
$cookieFile = tempnam ("/dev/null", "CURLCOOKIE");      
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
```

The response is not the page content but this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OKContent-Type: text/htmlCache-Control: no-cacheConnection: closeContent-Length: 670X-Iinfo: 8-65878311-0 0NNN RT(1497811103027 0) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1) B12(4,316,0)
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

here is the missing line of code which made it work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
```